# Using respond method in Grails 2.3.6 with json format and status code

Tags: json, grails, http-status-codes, grails-2.3

I'm trying to use the respond method that exists in grails 2.3 to return some exception message and a status code in JSON format, but haven't got success with the return code this far..

I've set an ExceptionController that will handle all the exceptions thrown by the rest of the controllers. Here it is:

```
class ExceptionController {

    static responseFormats = ['json','xml']

    def handleForbiddenException(ForbiddenException e){
        respond 'error':e.getMessage(),status:403
    }

    def handleNotFoundException(NotFoundException e){
        respond 'error':e.getMessage(),status:404
    }

    def handleInvalidRequestException(InvalidRequestException e){
        respond 'error':e.getMessage(), status:422
    }

    def handleGeneralException(Exception e){
        respond 'error':e.getMessage(),status:500
    }
}
```

But in a simple integration test, the result code is always 200..

I don't really know which is the correct format to use with this method to set the status code. I've tried several variations without success

```
respond 'error':e.getMessage(), status:422
respond e.getMessage(), status:422
respond object:['error':e.getMessage()], arguments:[status:422]
respond object:['error':e.getMessage()], model:[status:422]
respond object:['error':e.getMessage()], [status:422]
```

**UPDATE** I've found a format that works, but don't think it's the best solution...

```
respond JSON.parse("{'error':'${e.getMessage().encodeAsHTML()}'}"),[status:403]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/4e2f8de61f4383b92d79f5e34c3d1d0d151afb60. It seems you can use the property errorsHttpStatus but what I have read in the code is that you would need to pass an Errors instance not an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but that's not what I was asking

Comment: @Eylen and what were you asking? If you have a look at http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/single.html#restControllersStepByStep you will see that official documentation does not say anything about using status code with respond method and you will have to use the render method. Hope it helps!

Comment: Exactly. `render` helps in setting the status code. @Eylen There is no point in using `respond` for content negotiation if `JSON.parse` is used anyways. :)

Comment: I think I'm not getting the point... Respond cannot be used to return anything but status 200? What if I want to return for example an array but saying its a 403 forbidden for example?

Comment: It seems you cannot at the moment. Just raise a feature ticket if you think this would be useful.